# Find diff between two data frame based on primary key in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two data frame in spark.
I am doing `df1.except(df2)` two find if any columns has changed between two data frame .

df1 is like here

```
|001000900|aaaaa BELLOWS CORPORATION||N|
|001000905|ddddd DEPARTMENT OF LABOR AND EMPLOYMENT SECURITY|BUREAU OF COMPLIANCE|N|
|001001049|gggg RAVIOLI MFG CO INC|SPINELLI BKY RAVIOLI PASTRY SP|N|
|001001130|dddd ANGELES UNIFIED SCHOOL DISTRICT|TRANSPORTATION BRANCH|N|
|001001143|ffff MUSIC PARTIES, INC||N|
|001001155|BOSTON BRASS AND IRON CO||N|
|001001171|HANCOCK MARINE, INC.||N|
|001001184|TRILLION CORPORATION||N|
|001001192|HAWAII STATE CHIROPRACTIC ASSOCIATION INC||N|
|001001379|THE FRUIT SQUARE PEOPLE INC|L & M BAKERY|N|
|001001416|J & S MARKET||N|
```

df2 is like below

```
|001000145|PARADISE TAN||N|
|001000306|SHRUT & ASCH LEATHER COMPANY, INC.||N|
|001000355|HARRISON SPECIALTY CO., INC.||N|
|001000363|LOUIS M. GERSON CO., INC.||N|
|001000467|SAVE THE SEA TURTLES INTERNATIONAL|ADOPT THE BEACH HI|N|
|001000504|DIRIGO SPICE CORPORATION|CUNNINGHAM SPICE|N|
|001000744|FREEDMAN THREAD COMPANY|COLONIAL THREAD CO|N|
|001000756|AFFORDABLE AIR CONDITIONING|P R ENTERPRISE|N|
|001000900|CLIFLEX BELLOWS CORPORATION||N|
|001000905|FLORIDA DEPARTMENT OF LABOR AND EMPLOYMENT SECURITY|BUREAU OF COMPLIANCE|N|
|001001049|SPINELLI RAVIOLI MFG CO INC|SPINELLI BKY RAVIOLI PASTRY SP|N|
|001001130|LOS ANGELES UNIFIED SCHOOL DISTRICT|TRANSPORTATION BRANCH|N|
|001001143|TOSCO MUSIC PARTIES, INC||N|
|001001155|BOSTON BRASS AND IRON CO||N|
```

But what I want is that I have to find the diff between two data frame based on one column .Some thing like below

I want my output like below

```
|dunsnumber|filler1|        businessname|      tradestylename|registeredaddressindicator|
+----------+-------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------------+
| 001001130|       |dddd ANGELES UNIF...|TRANSPORTATION BR...|                         N|
| 001000900|       |aaaaa BELLOWS COR...|                    |                         N|
| 001000905|       |ddddd DEPARTMENT ...|BUREAU OF COMPLIANCE|                         N|
| 001001143|       |ffff MUSIC PARTIE...|                    |                         N|
| 001001049|       |gggg RAVIOLI MFG ...|SPINELLI BKY RAVI...|                         N|
+----------+-------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Here is my code

```
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
    val textRdd1 = sc.textFile("/home/cloudera/TRF/PCFP/INCR")
    val rowRdd1 = textRdd1.map(line => Row.fromSeq(line.split("\\|", -1)))
    var df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRdd1, schema)

    val textRdd2 = sc.textFile("/home/cloudera/TRF/PCFP/MAIN")
    val rowRdd2 = textRdd2.map(line => Row.fromSeq(line.split("\\|", -1)))
    var df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRdd2, schema)
    val diffAnyColumnDF = df1.except(df2).where(df1.col("dunsnumber") === 
    df2.col("dunsnumber")).show()
```

So if my primary key 'dunsnumber' matches then only find if any columns has changed or not for that primary key or not .

I hope my question clear.

Comment: You should join them with the key and use filter or select and apply the filter logic. :)

Comment: Do you want to subtract or simple except ? i.e Do you want the resulting dataframe coming from df1 only or from df1 and df2

Comment: @Avishek if primary key is same and then for the matching primary key if any of the belonging column value are different i need that value..

Comment: @RameshMaharjan yes thank you i did the same thing ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi so this has worked for me ..

```
val diffAnyColumnDF = df1.except(df2)
val addDF= diffAnyColumnDF.join(df2, Seq("dunsnumber")).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Dataframe doesn't have substract method. You can use an alternate approach though.
Convert data to RDD, use subtract method, get back to your dataframe.